# How do I get the current cursor on Edittext Android?

Tags: android

I want to get the cursor position on Edittext after each touch of the screen but after each touch of the **onTouchListener** event it returns the cursor position that was **previously selected**.

For example, I chose position number **59** in the text but I got the result position number **8**.

- Position **8** is the position I selected earlier

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = findViewById(R.id.text);

        text.setText("Java is a programming language and computing pla" +
                "tform first released by Sun Microsystems in 1995. There are" +
                "lots of applications and websites that will not work unless you have Java in" +
                "stalled, and more are created every day. Java is fast, secure, and reliable. " +
                "From laptops to datacenters, game consoles to scientific supercomputers, cell" +
                " phones to the Internet, Java is everywhere!\n");

        text.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int start = text.getSelectionStart();
        int end = text.getSelectionEnd();

        text.append(String.format("\nCurrent selection start=%s    end=%s",start, end));

        return false;
    }
 }
```

Result:

[image: result image]

Comment: try adding some delay (100-200 ms ) in onTouch method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "OnClickListener" to get cursor position. Because "onTouch" is called before the cursor position changes.

```
text.setOnClickListener {
        val start = text.getSelectionStart()
        val end = text.getSelectionEnd()
        Log.e("Log", "====>" + start + "  " + end)
}
```